# Determining if next iteration is going to happen

Tags: php, loops

I have a php script that loops many times. Is there a way in PHP to tell whether it was the last iteration ? Script is rather complex (1700 lines) and I can't locate the snippet responsible for running the script from the beginning.

Ideally I'm looking for a function (put in the end of the file) which predicts whether or not the script is going to run again from the beginning (as it does). Sure, other solutions are welcomed. The amount of iteration depends.

UPD:
Sorry, it's not loop that causes script to start over. There is something else (that I can't define) that makes the page to run from the beginning.

Comment: What kind of loop? Can you post the loop code?

Comment: Sorry I gave a wrong description, please see update.

Comment: Sounds like some pretty bad code. Maybe it needs a spot of restructuring so that it's easier to understand.

Comment: This problem sounds like it could be solved by using Threads: http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

Comment: Is the script starting over in a single run or is there a separate request that actually runs the script again and you are observing external side effects of the script running?

Comment: No, the code is well-written. It's a commercial script, it downloads page via cURL and displays it. The number of times script runs determined by the size of page being downloaded. I need to create a bandwidth meter, but its too many DB connections if I just save amount of traffic after each iteration. I need to collect data in SESSION variable and then save once in DB. Any solution to my problem would be great.

Comment: Jason M, I think the answer would be a separate request. As the whole script (which starts over and over) is not contained in any loop.

Comment: I'd try searching for die and exit in the script and making sure you log some info before ending the script. Also make sure that error messages are not being suppressed with @. Then check your error_log for some hints for why the script is ending prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean something like this:

```
$max = 10;

for($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
  if($i == $max) {
    //last iteration
  }
}
```

Comment: it will never enter the if statement `if($i == $max)`